# How can I save data from this code in separate files to create a machine learning model?

Tags: python, multithreading, machine-learning

So the goal is to record my mouse data and create a program that mimics human behavior to automate actions within a video game.

```
mouse_events = []


mouse.hook(mouse_events.append)
keyboard.start_recording()

keyboard.wait("a")

mouse.unhook(mouse_events.append)
keyboard_events = keyboard.stop_recording()

#Keyboard threadings:

k_thread = threading.Thread(target = lambda :keyboard.play(keyboard_events))
k_thread.start()

#Mouse threadings:

m_thread = threading.Thread(target = lambda :mouse.play(mouse_events))
m_thread.start()

#waiting for both threadings to be completed

k_thread.join()
m_thread.join()
```

Comment: The question isn't very clear, but I suggest you have a look at [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html?highlight=pickle#module-pickle).

Comment: Id like to create a machine-learning model from recorded mouse movement.  I don't know how to save the recorded mouse data.

Comment: So you wish to save this piece of code?

Comment: I want to save everything recorded into mouse_events[] to somehow create a machine learning model

Answer (score 0):

You can use pickle or joblib from scikit learn. Both have the function dump which will solve your problem.